# How to add option to the first in knockout js options?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have this code,

```
<select class="form-control" required data-bind="options: legends, value: statusToChange">
```

I have a legends array. I want to add "" (space) in the options. But I don't want to add that in the array.

I used knockout js for this application so I have self.legends() as the legends array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for the [`optionsCaption` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html):

> `optionsCaption`
>
> Sometimes, you might not want to select any particular option by default. But a single-select drop-down list usually starts with some item selected, so how can you avoid preselecting something? The usual solution is to prefix the list of options with a special dummy option that just reads “Select an item” or “Please choose an option” or similar, and have that one selected by default.
>
> This easy to do: just add an additional parameter with name `optionsCaption`, with its value being a string to display. For example:
>
> ```
> <select data-bind='options: myOptions, optionsCaption: "Select an item...", value: myChosenValue'></select>
> ```
>
> KO will prefix the list of items with one that displays the text “Select an item…” and has the value undefined. So, if `myChosenValue` holds the value `undefined` (which observables do by default), then the dummy option will be selected. If the `optionsCaption` parameter is an observable, then the text of the initial item will update as the observable’s value changes.

Example:

```js
var vm = {
  legends: ko.observableArray([
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "four"
  ]),
  legend: ko.observable()
};
vm.legend.subscribe(function(newValue) {
  console.log("Legend: " + newValue);
});
ko.applyBindings(vm, document.body);
```

```html
<select data-bind="options: legends, optionsCaption: 'legends', value: legend"></select>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @JohnArellano: What do you want instead? Literally `" "`? You can trivially create a computed that will convert `undefined` into some other value: `vm.legendComputed = ko.pureComputed(function() { var l = this.legend(); return l === undefined ? " " : l;};`

Comment: ...or create a computed array that you use for `options`, which is just the original array with your `" "` prepended.